# I am getting "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference" Error in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

The project was working correctly with no exception, then i started to get this error suddenly. I searched this error on forums and figured something about Razor so i updated Visual Studio but nothing changed. Details as below:

> An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Controller:

```
List<tablo_haber> haberler = db.tablo_haber.Where(x => x.language == "tr" && x.durum == "Aktif").OrderByDescending(x => x.id).Take(habersayisi).ToList();
ViewBag.news = haberler;
```

View:

```cs
<ul id="nt-example2" style="padding-left: 0px;">
     @foreach (tablo_haber veri in ViewBag.news)
     {
         <li data-infos="@veri.haber_metin">
             <span class="hour">
                 <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.veri.haber_res_1)" height="45" width="70" alt="@veri.haber_baslik" class="img-thumbnail" />
             </span>
             @if (ViewBag.dil == "ru")
             {
                 <a href="@Url.Action("index", "haber", new { id = veri.id})" style="color: #f2f2f2">
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; color: #F37021;"></i>@veri.haber_baslik
                 </a>
             }
             else
             {
                 <a href="@Url.Action("index", "haber", new { id = veri.id , baslik=veri.haber_baslik.Replace(" ","-").Replace("/","-").ToLower()})" style="color: #f2f2f2">
                     <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" style="float: right; cursor: pointer; color: #F37021;"></i>@veri.haber_baslik
                 </a>
             }
         </li>
     }
</ul>
```

Comment: You need to add the code in the question, not an image of it.

Comment: And the only relevant code is the GET method where you assign values to `ViewBag` since that's where you error is occurring

Comment: When i started with breakpoint, everything is normal, the data is coming, Its binding correctly.

Comment: The code you have shown will not cause that error. What will is something like `ViewBag.abc.xyz= ...`

Comment: It was working correctly like i said, there is nothing wrong about the code.

Comment: It caused by `ViewBag.veri.haber_res_1` :)

Comment: Thanks man, i am such a blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is thrown by by you use of `ViewBag.veri.haber_res_1` in the following line of code

```
<img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.veri.haber_res_1)" .... />
```

because `ViewBag.veri` is `null`

Based on your `foreach`, best guess is it should be

```
<img src="@Url.Content(veri.haber_res_1)" .... />
```